# How to resolve a relative path in node?

Tags: node.js

Came across this situation recently - I have an environment variable for a directory path like so:

```
var fooDir = process.env.FOO_DIR;
```

and I want to make sure this directory exists with a synchronous mkdir (at some point later):

```
fs.mkdirSync(fooDir, mode);
```

however if the user has supplied the environment variable via a realtive ~/ path node cannot resolve it

```
export FOO_DIR='~/foodir'
```

is there a way in node to resolve this without invoking a child process exec call to the actual shell?  currently my solution is to do a replace myself like so:

```
fooDir = fooDir.replace(/^~\//, process.env.HOME + '/');
```

just curious if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it right: ~ is expanded by the *shell*, not the OS, just like *. None of the C file functions that node.js wraps handle ~ either, and if you want this you have to do the replacement yourself, just as you've shown. I've done this myself in C when supporting config files that allow relative file paths.

However, you should probably handle the case where HOME isn't defined; I believe this happens with non-interaction logins with bash, for example, and the user could always choose to unset it.

Comment: yea thats what I thought.  I'll definitely add the HOME check, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to absolute path with `path.join`:

```js
const path = require('path')

const absolutePath = path.join(process.cwd(), relativePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Rekuire](https://npmjs.org/package/rekuire), it is a node module that solves the relative paths problem in NodeJs.